# Sequelize not creating any tables in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I just pulled a project to a new machine, I use PostgreSQL for my DB, sequelize as an ORM, and feathersjs and express or middleware. I try to start the project as I always do but it doesn't work.

I have an .env file with all my environment configuration info, what I usually do is first run `sequelize db:create`, to create the DB, after that, I use `npm start` to create the tables. However when I do it it doesn't create any table or show any error, it just shows the `info: Feathers application started on http://localhost:3030` but when I open pgAdmin the Database is empty. I tried logging in in sequelize but it's not showing anything at all. I also deleted the ENV and it doesn't show any error at `npm start` (it does show an error at `sequelize db:create`. This is driving me nuts.

Heres my sequelize.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { Op } = Sequelize;  
const operatorsAliases = {
   // ...
};

module.exports = function (app) {
  const connectionString = `postgres://${process.env.DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@` +
`${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`;

 const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionString, {
dialect: 'postgres',
dialectOptions: {
  ssl: false
},
logging: console.log,
operatorsAliases,
define: {
  freezeTableName: true
}
  });

const oldSetup = app.setup;

 app.set('sequelizeClient', sequelize);

app.setup = function (...args) {
 const result = oldSetup.apply(this, args);

// Set up data relationships
const models = sequelize.models;
Object.keys(models).forEach(name => {
  if ('associate' in models[name]) {
    models[name].associate(models);
  }
});

// Sync to the database
sequelize.sync({ logging: console.log });

return result;
 };
};
```

My npm start script just points to an app.js file where I just import sequelize with `app.configure(sequelize);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out is actually an issue with node 14. I had to install a newer version of node-Postgres (pg@8.0.3) as pointed out in [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158#issuecomment-618644494)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `sequelize db:migrate` after creating the database

Comment: The way the project is set up I have never had to do `db:migrate` before, the project doesn't even have a migration folder. I think this is going to be a deeper issue related to my new machine config